# Where is the process I executed throught the web page?

Tags: php

I am running a server on my localhost.
through my index HTML page I am executing proccesses, (with the help of php page).
Now, if I am running those programs by myself and not throught the web browser in the html page,
I can see them as applications in the Windows Task Manager (in the Applications bar), and also the windows of the applications themselvs, and the output in running time.
But when I am executing those apps throught the web page, I cannot see them at all (The server and the applications are on my computer)
Why is that? I want to be able to see the result they show me in running time but I cant.
Is there any way to change that?
OS: Windows XP
Server: WampServer 2.2

Comment: maybe your server is running with a different user?

Comment: which server you are running on your localhost?? machine you are at windows/mac/*nix ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you enable  **Show processes from all users** ?

[image]

Comment: I mean that I cant see them in the Applications bar, Nor as regular applications that has their own window.

Comment: Exactly because they run as a different user.